# How to get a notification about what changed in an entry

Tags: add-on, email

When an entry on my site is changed, an email is fired off using MX Notify Control (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control)

This is great, but I have no idea what changed. Sometimes it was just one checkbox or it might have been the whole page was rewritten.

I would like to get a better feel of what is different. It would be great to have a Diff type view for text, but even if I knew what fields had changed it would be a great.

Comment: This is a good question! I wonder if any of the add-ons have this feature. Maybe Better Workflow?

Comment: I would love to have some kind of logs of this too!

Comment: There isn't a way with MX Notify Control out of the box. You would need to write an add-on to handle it, the easiest way would be to make sure that you have versioning turned on for your entries then to grab the last 2 edited entries with your entry_id from the exp_entry_versioning table and then setup some logic to output the changes as you see fit.

Comment: Publisher has content diffs: http://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher/diffs

Comment: I have a client that is using Publisher for content diffs and they are extremely happy with it.

Comment: That's exactly what we are looking for. We would like to obtain details when a user changes his/her profile. Is there any chance this could work for us? Kind regards Richard

Answer (score 4):

There used to be an addon (for EE 1.x?) that was called Redline that would show the diff between entry versions.

Great to hear this is coming sometime in Better Workflow though!

Answer (score 2):

In the Better Workflow support forum, it seems that this functionality is on their
roadmap.
[Support Thread](http://betterworkflow.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/39-can-each-user-see-what-has-changed-between-the-live-draft-and-submitted-versions)

Comment: Keep in mind that was nearly a year ago. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have built a small plug-in that lets you extract last version (well in fact supporting a whole set of queries) for comparison with current entry. Issue is really with custom field types that store their data in other tables... no version info...

If folks think it would be useful to have that for 2.x I would be happy to git-hub it....